# Bootstrap 4 list group works in Firefox, not in Chrome or Edge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use the bootstrap 4 css framework, and I use a list group like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div>
        <div class="list-group">
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="/">Estonian Language</a>
            <br>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="/">International Winter Program</a>
            <br>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="/">Literature and Film in Vienna around 1900</a>
            <br>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="/">Business and Entrepreneurship in the Start-Up Nation</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which is similar to the example on the [bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/). It looks just like it should when I use Firefox, but when I use Chrome or Edge some gap is created between the different items. When I inspect the element it does not show a margin or some padding, so I don't know why this happens or how to solve it. Any idea's why this happens? Is it a bug?

[Bootply example here](https://www.codeply.com/go/L932k9juJf)

Comment: Remove the `<br>`'s, its not needed and is creating your problem

Comment: This is not like the example on the bootstrap site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using it as the getbootstrap site advises. You're using a div to identify your list group, and it is a ul>li structure.

From the getbootstrap site:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```